# How to upload file using GraphQL view UI

Tags: flask, graphene-python

There is a graphene upload file snippet here (http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/relay/mutations/#accepting-files). However, I am not sure how we can use this mutation on GraphQL view to upload the actual file.

There is no help available that explains how to upload file using GraphQL view UI as base.

```py
class UploadFile(graphene.ClientIDMutation):
     class Input:
         pass
         # nothing needed for uploading file

     # your return fields
     success = graphene.String()

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, root, info, **input):
        # When using it in Django, context will be the request
        files = info.context.FILES
        # Or, if used in Flask, context will be the flask global request
        # files = context.files

        # do something with files

        return UploadFile(success=True)
```

I tried this on GraphQL view,

```
mutation {
  upload_image( 

  ) {
    success
  }
}
```

This results in

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Syntax Error GraphQL (4:3) Expected Name, found )\n\n3:   \t\n4:   ) {\n     ^\n5:     success\n",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out how to test this file upload mutation. I used postman with "multipart form data" and send the parameters in the form (including file). That worked great.